# apt-broke after trying to install cuda

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

Ubuntu version: 18.04
Apt version: 1.6.13

I attempted to install a different cuda toolkit, and in doing so may have irrevocably broken apt. I believe the problem has nothing to do with cuda however, and that apt is at fault here.

If I run `sudo apt-get install *anything*` (or apt remove or apt purge) I get the error:

`Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done cuda is already the newest version (11.2.2-1). You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies. cuda-drivers-460 : Depends: libnvidia-common-460 (>= 460.32.03) but it is not going to be installed libnvidia-gl-460 : Depends: libnvidia-common-460 but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

so I try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`:

`Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local  libnvidia-common-460 460.32.03-0ubuntu1 [10.2 kB] Err:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local  libnvidia-common-460 460.32.03-0ubuntu1 File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local/./libnvidia-common-460_460.32.03-0ubuntu1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory) E: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local/./libnvidia-common-460_460.32.03-0ubuntu1_all.deb  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local/./libnvidia-common-460_460.32.03-0ubuntu1_all.deb (2: No such file or directory) E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

indeed `/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local` does not exist, let alone the files within.

Running `sudo apt-get update` yields:

`E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.105-418.39  Release' no longer has a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local  Release' no longer has a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

which again probably stems from not having `/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local` (or `/var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.105-418.39`)

following the advice from https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=281922
I have also tried:
`sudo su for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-440 | awk '{print $3}'); do dpkg-divert --remove $FILE; done exit`

but entering the line beginning `for FILE...` does nothing (nor does replacing `nvidia-440` with 450 or 460)

I am using apt version 1.6.13 which I have tried reinstalling by running `sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.13_amd64.deb` (downloaded from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.13_amd64.deb
) but I still get the same errors when running anything above

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - I would really like to avoid having to reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: Best to start fresh, with a working Nvidia driver installed, then apply the solution in either https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010  Both of which avoid the crazy web of dependencies on the cuda deb. You might get apt to work by purging all the problem packages at one time.  Even if you got the deps right, the first update of kernel or video driver breaks everything.

Comment: Not sure following advice from linux mint site is a good idea either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is as much a reply to @ubfan1 than anything, but the problem was I was unable to start afresh / remove any lingering cuda on my system. The answer in [How do I install NVIDIA and CUDA drivers into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063)

provided the magic: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*`
which then allowed me to run update followed by fix-broken install

Comment: Careful with this command.
I previously installed 2 versions of CUDA, and only one of them was from a failed attempt, and needed to be cleaned up.
If you're in a similar situation, better to go into the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and remove only the version of CUDA you're not using.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-ubuntu2004-11-7-local.list` fixed the `sudo apt update` noise for me (while not deleting the other cuda* files as in w1nter's answer). Here's the transcript:

```
(torch) sharker@persephone:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for sharker: 
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local  Release
Err:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local  Release
  File not found - /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local/Release (2: No such file or directory)
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:9 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                          
Hit:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release                           
Hit:11 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]  
Hit:3 https://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal-12 InRelease   
Hit:8 https://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal-14 InRelease
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.7 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [391 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,024 B]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                                
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-7-local  Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

After consulting w1nter's answer I removed the `sudo apt update` errors with:

```
(torch) sharker@persephone:/var$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
(torch) sharker@persephone:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
cuda-ubuntu2004-11-7-local.list   dropbox.list        google-chrome.list.save
cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list       dropbox.list.save
cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list.save  google-chrome.list
(torch) sharker@persephone:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls -la
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 24 13:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May 15 20:27 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108 May  4 12:10 cuda-ubuntu2004-11-7-local.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  139 May 15 20:27 cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  139 May 15 20:27 cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   65 May 15 20:27 dropbox.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   65 May 15 20:27 dropbox.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 May 15 20:27 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 May 15 20:27 google-chrome.list.save
(torch) sharker@persephone:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm cuda-ubuntu2004-11-7-local.list 
(torch) sharker@persephone:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt update
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
Ign:3 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                     
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:7 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release                                       
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                       
Hit:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                         
Hit:1 https://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal-12 InRelease   
Hit:6 https://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal-14 InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
19 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
(torch) sharker@persephone:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt upgrade
```