# Steam asks for some other NVIDIA drivers, and games freeze/crash

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam

I recently installed steam on my Kubuntu 20.04 LTS machine using the .deb from their website, and on launch, it opens a terminal asking me to install other Nvidia drivers.

I run `Nvidia-driver-470` proprietary drivers on my 1660ti. (also tried `nvidia-driver-495`) 
Other specs in my PC are: 
i7 8700 
16GB ram

here is a screenshot of the terminal steam opens on startup:

[image: terminal screenshot]

I press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  after the 1st prompt, and it asks for the `root` password, then prints out what is seen in picture 1. After the second prompt pressing   <kbd>Enter</kbd>   closes the terminal window and opens steam immediately. It does this for every startup.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge steam steam-launcher
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Steam && rm -rf ~/.steam
sudo apt clean && sudo apt -f install
```

Installing steam after that fixes nothing.

The worst of all is, most of the games don't even work. They either freeze or crash at startup or midway. And it is not only the games that use Proton (i use 6.3), games like Portal 2, which run natively I believe also crash.

I have googled and found no solutions so please help.

The output of `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`

[image: output of sudo ubuntu-drivers devices]

```
apt list --installed | grep libnvidia                                                                                               [3:59:44]

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnvidia-cfg1-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-extra-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-470/unknown,now 470.82.01-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall                                                                                                     [4:18:44]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-495-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-modules-nvidia-495-5.11.0-43-generic (= 5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-495 (>= 495.44) but 495.29.05-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

all ppas connected to nvidia

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /
```

all ppas connected to steam

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:# Uncomment these lines to try the beta version of the Steam launcher
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:#deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:#deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ beta steam
```

Thanks in advance, and if there is any more info you need, post a comment and I'll edit the question

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`.

Comment: added it. note that the screenshot is taken on 495 proprietary drivers due to testing

Comment: Run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and check if the problem is solved.

Comment: nothing installed, upgraded, or got removed

Comment: Can you post the output of `apt list --installed | grep libnvidia` please post the output as text instead of an image.

Comment: tried with 470, outputs are updated

Comment: Ok, ask a new question regarding the errors while running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` if that got a fix, then this will also be fixed.

Comment: will do, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: no, it does unfortunately not

Comment: Are you getting the drivers from a ppa? I see in the output you are using a problematic ppa but I don't think that one is contributing to the issue. What ppas are you using?

Comment: Im getting the drivers from settings > driver manager

Comment: There is not enough information given to tell but my guess is this is happening because of the *developer.download.nvidia.com* ppa.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have managed to fixed my issue with the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431461/how-to-remove-cuda-completely-from-ubuntu) thread on stackoverflow

The issue was cuda

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you found the solution that works for you and decided to write an answer and accept your answer as correct. Contributing to this site helps everyone. Unfortunately your answer needs some improvement. A link only answer does not meet the standards of this site as links break all the time as websites close or move or change therr URL. Please edit your answer and add the essential steps needed to solve the problem in your answer and keep the link as a reference. I am down-voting your answer for this reason. If you edit your answer I will reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

You have learned that you cannot randomly throw packages/libraries together from different sources and expect things to work.  Nvidia drivers (either 470 or 495) and steam packages are available from the standard repos (restricted, multiverse) -- use them. CUDA does offer a .run file for installation which allows you to put libraries and executables into your own directories instead of system areas (avoids the crazy dependencies of trying the deb installation route or polluting system areas with wrong versions of things). Skip any offer of an Nvidia driver, you got a working one from the standard repos.

[how to install cuda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063)

[cuda location selection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010)

Clean out all the unnecessary steam and cuda, and who knows what else from your repositories.  Ensure the multiverse and restricted selections are made from the Software and Updates/sources tab, then update your package info with
sudo apt-get update
then just install the desired cuda drivers and steam.  The steam package may need the 32 bit libraries, but you probably got those already.  The only steam packages I have are steam:i386, steam-installer, and steam-devices, and steam games run fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but i failed to make it work.