# Errors while running ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management

i have an issue with nvidia drivers causing steam games to freeze or crash.
more is explained in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384678/steam-asks-for-some-other-nvidia-drivers-and-games-freeze-crash), where i have been told that if the errors from `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` were fixed, steam would also work.

the output of the command is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-495-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-modules-nvidia-495-5.11.0-43-generic (= 5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-495 (>= 495.44) but 495.29.05-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using 470 proprietary drivers on my nvidia 1660ti on kubuntu 20.04 LTS

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install                                                                                                      [18:58:54]
[sudo] password for lovro: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavresample4 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 python-is-python2 python3-pyudev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

thanks in advance

Comment: +1 Please [edit] and include the output of `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: done, it did nothing, yet it printed a not required package connected to this: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386