# nsight-related failure when installing cuda11.3 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, cuda

I am trying to install cuda 11.3 on a ubuntu 22.04 system following the instructions on the official site:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-3-1-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local
[image]

Everything's fine until the last line:

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

which gives the following error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../51-cuda-11-3_11.3.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-11-3 (11.3.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cuda.
Preparing to unpack .../52-cuda_11.3.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda (11.3.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-aYjp8G/38-nsight-compute-2021.1.1_2021.1.1.5-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-aYjp8G/40-nsight-systems-2021.1.3_2021.1.3.14-1_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Seems to be something with nsight? What to do with this? btw I am using a rtx 3090 with 515 driver.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010  I use the .run file without sudo, reject any Nvidia driver offer, and write everything into a location I select (e.g. /usr/local/data/apps/cuda-11.3), making the /usr/local writeable to accept the scripts location of /usr/local/cuda-11.3, then move it where I want it, restoring the original permissions on /usr/local.

Comment: @ubfan1 thx! how do you select the location? Do I get to select it during the course or before running the runfile?

Comment: Each release's run file is slightly different -- maybe you can select location to override in 11.3, but in 11.7, the install location was fixed at /usr/local/cuda-11.7, and even making the cuda-11.7 directly in advance (with write permissions failed to work). Select lib location as /usr/local/cuda-11.3/libs  instead of a system location, etc.