# Ubuntu 22.04 how to install Nvidia drivers and Cuda for GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

[image: everything greyed out]

Edit:  This is a lower grade GPU than GeForce GTX so I had to go with an older Nvidia driver.  See my answer for the answer but the question shows some problems along the way.

Everything else is greyed out except Continue using manually installed driver's radio button is selected.

Steps I took:

Followed the download from Nvidia way from here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04

Disabled
/blacklisted Nouveau as shown here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-blacklist-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux

Then followed this on how to get Nvidia in a Secure Boot device as shown here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-blacklist-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux
(use Google Translate)

What I want on my Lenovo Ideapad 3 Gaming 15ACH6 is to be able use Cuda and Cudnn.  I can use Cuda in Windows (dual boot) but prefer working in Ubuntu.

I followed many tutorials so am completely lost on what steps to take at this point.

Edit:

I did `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf` to comment out the blacklist lines and rebooted so now Ubuntu is detecting both monitors but nouveau is still greyed out in additional drivers in software and updates.

I wanted to go back to nouveau then purge nvidia and then try to choose one of the nvidia drivers listed in additional drivers, ie. purge the nvidia driver I downloaded and installed called `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.60.11.run`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063 or
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010   Clean out what you did, remove any nvidia drivers and blacklists, then starting from the Ubuntu repositories (restricted), install the Nvidia driver for your card (I use the 520, not the 520-open).  The cuda .run file offers an Nvidia driver, reject it.  I override all the system lib location with the cuda/lib location, (take ownership of /usr/local, run script as user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update CUDA:

https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html

```
0-Gaming-3:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Mar 21 22:42:37 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.30.02              Driver Version: 530.30.02    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti      On | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   41C    P8               N/A / 120W|    348MiB /  4096MiB |      3%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

or:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
```

or:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed @ubfan's advice but got stuck on a `sudo apt update` that said something about missing an Nvidia release file so I purged Nvidia again, checked `ubuntu-drivers devices` because I noticed my GPU is not GeForce GTX 1650 as advertised when I bought it but

```
nyck33@nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6:~$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
```

It's a lower grade GPU for thinner notebooks so I decided to go with the oldest driver and followed this:  https://itslinuxfoss.com/fix-failed-initialize-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch-error/

because I was getting a mismatch error.

Now I have

```
nyck33@nyck33-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ACH6:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Dec  1 21:15:11 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03   Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P0     6W /  N/A |      4MiB /  3914MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2076      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```