# Additional drivers not showing in ubuntu22.04LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-geforce

`$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
I had run this code then , it is showing that

All the available drivers are already installed.

but when there is no additional drivers neither nvidia nor any other in software and update -> Additional drivers app

Note : I have just already installed ubuntu 22.04 and want to switch into the nvidia driver
also i tried
`$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-535`

but

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-driver-535





How do I install nvidia gtx 1650  driver ??
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 how to install Nvidia drivers and Cuda for GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443232/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-and-cuda-for-geforce-gtx-1650-mobile) Further reference https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/09/26/nvidia-gtx-1650-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation-guide/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: I have the same issue,what a solution for this could be?