# Can not install cuda-drivers-530 (= 530.30.02-1) from Nvidia, dependency error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, cuda

Here is what I tried:

> TEMP_DEB="$(mktemp)"
>
> wget -O "$TEMP_DEB"
> 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-drivers_530.30.02-1_amd64.deb'
>
> sudo dpkg -i "$TEMP_DEB"

But I got this error:

> Preparing to unpack /tmp/tmp.6XsSKWJAC0 ... Unpacking cuda-drivers
> (530.30.02-1) over (530.30.02-1) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of cuda-drivers:  cuda-drivers depends on
> cuda-drivers-530 (= 530.30.02-1); however:   Package cuda-drivers-530
> is not installed.

Its so funny because I am installing cuda-drivers-530. How could it be installed and be a dependency of what I install?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please quote your pastes as {code} pastes as not as *text* pastes.  It's harder to read when you quote formatted text as if it's *prose*.

Comment: It's right there in your output: You are attempting to install package `cuda-drivers`, version 530. That package depends upon a different package `cuda-drivers-530`, version 530, which you have not yet downloaded nor installed.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010  The Ubuntu 22.04 standard repos have Nvidia 530.41.03, newer than the one offered by your deb package.  The cuda packages can be installed without being tangled up with any dependencies.