# CUDA package problems: Can't update Ubuntu 22 due to 'unmet dependecies'

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, dependencies, cuda

So I am pretty new to Linux. I played around with installing CUDA libraries for some ML experiments on my linux system. However since a couple of weeks I have not been able to get updates to my system duo to some broken cuda packages?

My problem basically goes as follows:

```
sudo apt update 

Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local  InRelease [1.575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local  InRelease [1.572 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-3-local  InRelease [1.572 B]                                            
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local  InRelease [1.575 B]                                            
Get:4 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.9.6.50  InRelease [1.572 B]                                       
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local  InRelease [1.572 B]                                            
Get:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-3-local  InRelease [1.572 B]                                            
Get:4 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.9.6.50  InRelease [1.572 B]                                       
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                       
Hit:6 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease                                                       
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                  
Hit:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease                     
Hit:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  InRelease                     
Hit:10 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                      
Get:11 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]                                     
Hit:12 https://repo.jellyfin.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                         
Hit:13 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                       
Hit:14 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/amd64  InRelease
Hit:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 229 kB in 1s (205 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
117 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

The I run:

```
 sudo apt install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-command-line-tools-12-3 : Depends: cuda-cupti-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                                Depends: cuda-nvprof-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                                Depends: cuda-nvtx-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
 cuda-compiler-12-3 : Depends: cuda-cuxxfilt-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                      Depends: cuda-nvcc-12-3 (>= 12.3.103) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
 cuda-libraries-12-3 : Depends: cuda-cudart-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                       Depends: cuda-nvrtc-12-3 (>= 12.3.103) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                       Depends: cuda-opencl-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                       Depends: libcublas-12-3 (>= 12.3.4.1) but 12.3.2.9-1 is installed
                       Depends: libcufft-12-3 (>= 11.0.12.1) but 11.0.11.19-1 is installed
                       Depends: libcurand-12-3 (>= 10.3.4.101) but 10.3.4.52-1 is installed
                       Depends: libcusolver-12-3 (>= 11.5.4.101) but 11.5.3.52-1 is installed
                       Depends: libcusparse-12-3 (>= 12.2.0.103) but 12.1.3.153-1 is installed
                       Depends: libnpp-12-3 (>= 12.2.3.2) but 12.2.2.32-1 is installed
                       Depends: libnvjitlink-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                       Depends: libnvjpeg-12-3 (>= 12.3.0.81) but 12.2.3.32-1 is installed
 cuda-libraries-dev-12-3 : Depends: cuda-cudart-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: cuda-cccl-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: cuda-profiler-api-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: cuda-driver-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: cuda-nvrtc-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.103) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: cuda-opencl-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: libcublas-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.4.1) but 12.3.2.9-1 is installed
                           Depends: libcufft-dev-12-3 (>= 11.0.12.1) but 11.0.11.19-1 is installed
                           Depends: libcurand-dev-12-3 (>= 10.3.4.101) but 10.3.4.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: libcusolver-dev-12-3 (>= 11.5.4.101) but 11.5.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: libcusparse-dev-12-3 (>= 12.2.0.103) but 12.1.3.153-1 is installed
                           Depends: libnpp-dev-12-3 (>= 12.2.3.2) but 12.2.2.32-1 is installed
                           Depends: libnvjitlink-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
                           Depends: libnvjpeg-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.0.81) but 12.2.3.32-1 is installed
 cuda-nvcc-12-3 : Depends: cuda-nvvm-12-3 (= 12.3.52-1) but 12.3.103-1 is installed
                  Depends: cuda-crt-12-3 (= 12.3.52-1) but 12.3.103-1 is installed
 cuda-toolkit-12-3 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
 cuda-visual-tools-12-3 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-12-3 (>= 12.3.101) but 12.3.52-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**Then when I try**

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I get the following:

```
...*long code paragraphs*
    101-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-nvml-dev-12-3 (12.3.101-1) over (12.3.52-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/31-cuda-nvml-dev-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb (--unpack)
:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include', which is also in package cuda-cccl-12-3 12.3.52-1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/00-cuda-cupti-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/01-cuda-cupti-dev-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/02-cuda-nvprof-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/03-cuda-nvtx-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/04-cuda-cuxxfilt-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/05-cuda-cudart-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/06-cuda-cccl-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/07-cuda-driver-dev-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/08-cuda-cudart-dev-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/09-cuda-nvcc-12-3_12.3.103-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/10-cuda-nvrtc-12-3_12.3.103-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/11-cuda-opencl-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/12-libcublas-12-3_12.3.4.1-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/13-libcufft-12-3_11.0.12.1-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/14-libcurand-12-3_10.3.4.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/15-libcusolver-12-3_11.5.4.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/16-libcusparse-12-3_12.2.0.103-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/17-libnpp-12-3_12.2.3.2-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/18-libnvjitlink-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/19-libnvjpeg-12-3_12.3.0.81-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/20-cuda-profiler-api-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/21-cuda-nvrtc-dev-12-3_12.3.103-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/22-cuda-opencl-dev-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/23-libcublas-dev-12-3_12.3.4.1-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/24-libcufft-dev-12-3_11.0.12.1-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/25-libcurand-dev-12-3_10.3.4.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/26-libcusolver-dev-12-3_11.5.4.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/27-libcusparse-dev-12-3_12.2.0.103-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/28-libnpp-dev-12-3_12.2.3.2-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/29-libnvjitlink-dev-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/30-libnvjpeg-dev-12-3_12.3.0.81-1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-VjvbGI/31-cuda-nvml-dev-12-3_12.3.101-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Can somebody please tell me how to fix this?**

Comment: Remove those `file:...` and all third party PPA repositories then run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010
Basically avoid tangling CUDA up with your system files or package manager, and use its private location for bin and lib.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to wonderful world of CUDA and NVIDIA :-)

Basically, you (most likely) are trying to update your CUDA installation and it's updates are incompatible with your installed NVIDIA drivers.  This is most often caused by installing NVIDA drivers from your distribution and then installing CUDA via the NVIDIA developers CUDA Toolkit [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html].

The solution(s) are either (a) wait for your distribution to update their driver packages so that the version numbers satisfy the CUDA update requirements OR (b) remove/purge the installed NVIDIA drivers and then install both NVIDIA drivers AND the CUDA from NVIDIA.  The *disadvantage* of this second method is that there is often some special tweaks that the DISTRO maintainers do to the NVIDIA packages to mitigate any issues with their specific distribution.

Comment: There is room for improvement in your answer like addressing the local `file:...` repositories as those are most likely old and probably don't reflect their online equivalents and the other third party PPA repositories ... Those need to be disabled/updated before any other APT action can be attempted or the result might be the same or even worse ... I think

Comment: Yeah, right - probably should uninstall/purge everything and start again - less likely to have any conflicts.

Comment: Problem is that I can't seem to uninstall either nvidia-cuda-toolkit or nvidia in general since I keep getting the same broken dependencies error...

Comment: I'd uninstall everything NVIDIA and CUDA and start from scratch.