# Running CUDA on GTX Titan Black in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, cuda, gpu-driver

I recently got a hold of 2 GTX Titan Black's and I was trying to get CUDA running on them.
But as of now I couldn't get CUDA to work on this PC.
I'm using Driver version 470.223.02 with CUDA version 11.4 and Ubuntu 22.04.
When trying to download the CUDA toolkit for that version the latest Ubuntu version supported is 20.04. Is there any way to get CUDA running on this system without reinstalling Ubuntu (downgrading to 20.04)?

`nvidia-smi` report:

[image: Nvidia-smi report]

Comment: Sure, keep the CUDA files under the .../cudaxxx install directory instead of sprinkling them into the system areas and reject any video driver offer. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010

Comment: When trying to let Tensorflow (Python) detect the GPU's none of them show up, do i need to install something else / additional?

Comment: Four yr. old notes on Tensorflow 2.2 rc2: installed the nvidia-cuda-dev pkg, but wasn't sure that had anything to do with getting it working. Haven't run it in years. Can you run the CUDA samples? Next get the dnn working, then try tensorflow.

Comment: The weird thing is that PyTorch detects both GPU's and Tensorflow doesn't