# Cannot install nvidia drivers with .run

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, compiling, linux-headers

i was using nvidia omniverse, and a very simple scene crashed every time i opened it.
I looked up a fix, and i found this page (https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/dev-guide/latest/linux-troubleshooting.html) telling me to remove old nvidia drivers, and install with **NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-550.54.14.run** file.

When i booted into recovery kernel, using root i tried installing the .run, but i received an error that the kernel couldn't be compiled.
(the error occurs with both 550 and 535 drivers)

This is apparently the solution
**"if the kernel could not be compiled, make sure to download headers and image files related to your linux kernel before the driver installation."**

I realize the page tells me the solution, but i don't understand, because with my very limited knowledge i thought the kernel headers already existed in '/usr/src/'.

I almost sure i'm misunderstanding things, because i am not well read with linux.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Kernel: 6.5.0-21-generic

OS: ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

GPU: 3070 ti oc

CPU: ryzen 3700x

Comment: You've provided no details, such as the version of Ubuntu, your video card, and the driver version you tried to install. Don't reply in a comment, edit your question and give the crucial information.

Comment: You will avoid massive problems when updating kernels by using the Nvidia drivers supplied in the standard Ubuntu repos. If you really want the 550 driver, you can get it via the graphics-drivers ppa. Just use the .run script to create a CUDA install dir with all bin and lib files (use options to override the system locations for these).See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010

Comment: You mention 22.04.3 as your release, which if correct, means you're behind on applying security fixes to your system. [This link for 22.04.4](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, however installed systems upgraded to it in the week before the ISO release; are you sure you're using 22.04.3? as that shows a potential other problem that I'd fix first (*may indirectly help here too*)  FYI:  22.04.3 maybe what you installed; if you applied security fixes that will upgrade; you can use `lsb_release -a` to check what you're running.